# Apache user read/write folder permissions with PHP - compex multi-user situation?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, user-controls, permissions

I'm thinking of how to allow users to set up new areas using PHP. Creating the folders and files would be done during signup.

Users would then be able to upload various files, including PHP files, to their area.

What I want to do is separate out the different areas, so if a user's area is /user1/ they can't access someone else's file like this:

```
fopen('../user2/file.php');
```

or write to another user's area like this:

```
file_put_contents('../user2/file.php', $mybadcontent);
```

Basically I want to be able to completely separate out each user area, so they can't access or execute each other's files.

Is this even possible? Is it going to be complex Apache rules, using htaccess?

Comment: Is Virtual Hosts the right way to go? Logic tells me that is is, but if anyone could confirm, that would be great!

http://www.jacmoe.dk/multiple-local-apache-virtual-hosts

Comment: Hey. Take a quick peek at http://serverfault.com/questions/451011/isolating-apache-virtualhosts-from-the-rest-of-the-system

Comment: And is another option to use php.ini open_basedir configurations on a directory by directory basis? Looks like it could be exactly what's needed...

Comment: Awesome, thanks Anthony. I'll have a read through the suggestions there.